# Why is SwiftUI not setting a state variable from decoded JSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

I am trying to download a JSON list of first names and use them to randomly pick a name. However when I step through in the debugger I see that self.names is not being set to the parsed JSON. Why is this?

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @State var names:[String] = []
  init(){
      getNames()
  }
  var body: some View {
      List {displays person objects from coredata}
      Button(action: addItem)
  }

  func getNames(){
    // URL & JSON setup
    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {return}
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedNames = try decoder.decode([String].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.names = decodedNames // self.names not being set here
            }
        }
        catch {}
    }.resume()
  }
  
  func addItem() {
      let p = Person(context: viewContext)
      p.age = String(Int.random(in: 1...100))
      p.name = self.names[Int.random(in: 0..<self.names.count)] // crashes here
      try! viewContext.save()
  }
```

Comment: in `catch`, you're not doing anything if there's an error. How do you know if it's decoding properly? Try `print(error)` inside the catch block. I also wouldn't use the `random` method you're using (as you can see, it crashes if the range is invalid). Instead, maybe something like: `p.name = self.names.randomElement() ?? "Default name"` and make sure you check to see if there are `names` to chose from first.

Comment: Are you sure the data is being decoded? You have not done any air handling in your catch block, so there may be an error that you’re not seeing.

Comment: In my debugger panel I can see decodedNames with the expected string array, and it does not hit a breakpoint inside of catch.

Comment: In general, asynchronous calls shouldn't be done inside a `View`, which is transient. Move all of the async work to a view model (`ObservableObject` with a `@Published` property) and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'm curious why though? It seems like the same thing just moved around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views in SwiftUI do not have a guaranteed lifespan. They're transitive by nature and the system can rebuild them at any time. If you have an asynchronous method in a View, there is no guarantee that this same instance of the View will exist in the hierarchy by the time it returns.

For this reason, it's generally recommended that you move asynchronous code to a view model (`ObservableObject` with a `@Published` property). The `ObservableObject` will have a guaranteed lifespan and can communicate the data back to the view via the `@Published` property.